# Running ANOVA test after melt function

Tags: r, anova, reshape2, melt

I am trying to run an ANOVA test after using melt and the error keeps popping up. I do not know what I'm doing wrong

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'W' not found

rm(list=ls())

Measurements=matrix(c(1.4,1.6,1.8,2.4,2.1,2.1,2.3,2.4,2.6,2.7,2.5,2.1,1.2,1.9,2.0,2.4,2.2,2.2,2.3,2.3,2.3,2.0,2.2,2.3,1.0,1.3,1.8,2.0,2.1,2.0,2.1,2.4,2.4,2.5,2.3,2.1,2.2,2.9,3.2,3.9,3.5,3.6,3.3,3.6,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0,2.3,3.2,3.9,4.0,4.0,4.1,3.9,4.0,3.9,3.7,3.9,4.1,1.3,1.7,1.9,2.3,2.2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.2,2.3,2.5,2.6,3.1,3.2,3.9,4.7,4.3,4.1,4.3,4.5,4.3,4.4,4.8,5.0,3.5,3.8,3.9,5.4,5.1,5.0,5.2,5.4,5.5,5.4,5.5,5.8,2.0,2.3,2.8,3.6,3.4,3.3,3.3,3.6,3.7,3.6,3.7,3.8),nrow=36)

colnames(Measurements)=c("Rest","Walk","Play")

Measurements=data.frame(Measurements)

write.csv(Measurements,"TanyaG_Measurements_data.csv")

Measurements

boxplot(Measurements,ylab="Ounces",xlab="Dogs_Activity",main="Water_Intake",notch=FALSE)

install.packages("reshape2")

library(reshape2)

reshape2::melt

ALL<-melt(Measurements,variable.name="A",value.name="W")

ALL

AnovaTest<- aov(W~A,data.frame="ALL")

summary(AnovaTest)
```

I have tried changing the names, changing the codes and i can not seem to figure out what to do

Comment: Change to `aov(W~A,data.frame=ALL)`

Comment: i changed it and I am still getting the same error: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'W' not found"

Comment: Try `aov(W~A, data=ALL)`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it worked! I have tried EVERYTHING from changing the matrix to using different names and codes but nothing has worked! i could hug you rn! i appreciate you

Comment: Going forward, as one of your troubleshooting steps, check the help page for the function, using `?aov`.